# Tastypie: Getting error during create_response()

Tags: django, tastypie

When I try to override the `obj_create`, I got an error message and I don't understand why.

Here is the code:

In `api.py`:

```
class CardInfoResource(ModelResource):

    linked_client = fields.ForeignKey(ClientInfoResource, 'linked_client',
        blank=True, null=True, full=True)

    class Meta(CommonResourceMeta):
        queryset = Card.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'card_infos'
        fields = ['custom_pk']
        list_allowed_methods = ['post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['post']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        # some stuff
        mydata = {'foo':'bar'}
        return self.create_response(request, mydata)
```

When sending a `POST` request to `myAPI`/`card_infos`/ with a payload with some data (unused in the above example), I'm getting a JSON with:

- An error message:

  > NoneType' object has no attribute 'GET'
- A traceback (I'm not going to paste the full stack, gut the error occurs on the `create_response()` and the responsible method is `determine_format()`:
      if request.GET.get(\'format\'):\n\nAttributeError: \'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'GET\'\n')

It seems that the error is related to the `Request=None` in the `obj_create` definition, but still no idea how to fix it.

My purpose can seem weird but I just want to POST some data without writing it in the DB. That's why I call `create_response` with some data inside an overridden 
`obj_create()` method. Not sure that is a clean way thought...

Comment: post the create_response() code and determine_format() method

Comment: This is not my code. It's the tastypie one. But I just figured out that the error is related to the `"request=None"` in the obj_create. But still don't know how to fix it

Comment: @DavidD. Did you get any answer to it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.GET` on a object which does not have that attribute. We can see from the traceback that this object is a [`None`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) singleton, and we can see that this doesn't have a `.GET` attribute using the [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) built in.

```
>>> dir(None)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__',     '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

In `obj_create()` the keyword argument `request` defaults to `None` if no request keyword argument is passed.

So I expect you are calling that method and not passing a `HttpRequest` object as a kwarg, and this means we pass `None` to the `create_response()` function. This probably expects the `request` variable passed to be a `HttpRequest` object which has a [`.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) attribute - however as it is not a `AttributeError` is raised.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Any idea how to solve this? My purpose can seem weird but I just want to POST some data without writing it in the DB. That's why I call `create_response` with some data inside an overriden `obj_create()` method. Not sure that is a clean way thought...

Comment: Any request should be handled by the URLconf, and this should pass a request object to some view to handle the response. You just need to pass that request object through the stack so it gets to the obj_create() function and then the create_response function. What is calling obj_create()

Comment: what is calling obj_create()

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure to understand. Any sample code to provide?
To answer your question, in resources.py (tastypie file), the post_list method calls  obj_create this way :

`bundle = self.build_bundle(data=dict_strip_unicode_keys(deserialized), request=request)
        updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))`

Comment: This is not an answer, I have the same problem and no solution.